# Open-source server OS image management software

Tags: linux, open-source, server

For a home-built datacenter, I am searching for a software which handles creating, installing & updating OS images.

It should have the following features;

- web interface (command line client ist also acceptable)
- send different OS images to servers
- initiate update process (install new image & reboot)
- create different group of servers (e.g. "web" "database") and push new images to a specific group
- different update strategies (e.g. only one server at a time)
- create OS images (taking code from git and installing it; OPTIONAL)

It should run on Ubuntu Server.
A combination of software may also be possible: One software which handles updating the hardware servers from images which are created by another piece of software. If possible, the software should not be bloated and contain a bunch of other features, but instead be specific for this task.

Note: Bonus point if the application provides an HTTP API.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Clonezilla Server Edition](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-SE/) and its core networking part [DRBL](https://drbl.org/about/#Install_one_server_you_have_all_clients).  It can

- create images
- install new images
- supports different images going to different servers
- using images diskless (without disks on clients)
- many more

It does not:

- have a web interface

Answer (score 1):

I think [Fog Project](https://fogproject.org) may hit more of your requirements than [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org) but does not meet them all. It's centralised and will push images over the wire but you've to update the master images yourself.